# Android intent with multiple option i.e , Pick image from gallary and capture image using front camera

Tags: java, android

After selecting/capturing the image i need to crop the image.

I already done this one.but the problem is when i am switching to the android latest version(kitkat) crop intent is not working properly.

**My Code**

```
    private void picPhoto() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        pickIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    } else {
        pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        pickIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        pickIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    }
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileDirectory());
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);

    String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture";
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);

    chooserIntent.putExtra
            (
                    Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent}
            );

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

**Can any one help with me an example ?**

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to crop a pic which was working in kitkat too

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            final Intent data) {
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&&requestCode==1) {  

                     performCrop(image_uri);

}
}
    private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {

        thePic = null;

        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // // // indicate output X and Y

            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println("out of memoryyy");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", width);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think this should be write inside OnActivityResult.can't we set crop along with gallary intent much like my above code ? thanks for your support :)

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_PICK,
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1); check my edit for activityresult

Comment: Karthika  :) i mean this code only we can use after calling gallary/camera intent.i dont want to do like this way by calling from onactivty result.my question is  can we set like this                                                                                                                    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
         pickIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
         pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         pickIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

Comment: @AnoopM when i used this i got a layout with the images from my gallery and clicking on one of the image the cropimage window of device will get open do you want a functionality other than this?

Comment: fine while looking up functionality not the way of coding..I seems it's better to use external library to get rid from app crash..thanks you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

**So this is it..**

```
   private void picPhoto() {
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        pickIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    } else {
        pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        pickIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    }
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileDirectory());
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);

    String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture";
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);

    chooserIntent.putExtra
            (
                    Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent}
            );

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

**All features will work Api >14 ie , Android 4.0 (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH).**

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri _uri = data.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(_uri);
                // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
                String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                // where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                        query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

                String filePath = "";
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
                cursor.close();
                croppedPath = filePath;
            } else {
                //User had pick an image.
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                //Link to the image
                final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                croppedPath = imageFilePath;
                cursor.close();
            }
            if (croppedPath != null) {
                cropIntent(croppedPath, 5);
            }
        } else if (requestCode != 4 && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data == null) {
            cropIntent(getFileDirectory().getPath(), 4);
        } else if (requestCode == 4) {
            editPhoto1.setImageBitmap(null);
            if (bmp != null) {
                bmp.recycle();
            }
            setImagePicked(getFileDirectory().getPath(), 0);
        } else if (requestCode == 5) {
            if (croppedPath != null) {
                editPhoto1.setImageBitmap(null);
                if (bmp != null) {
                    bmp.recycle();
                }
                setImagePicked(getFileDirectory().getPath(), 0);
                croppedPath = null;
            }
        }
    }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Crop method**

```
 private void cropIntent(String fileToCrop, int requestCode) {
    Uri filePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileToCrop));
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(filePath, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getFileDirectory());
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, requestCode);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
}
```