# Camera app stops the activity which started it so MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT is null?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting the camera app from my activity

```
public void startCamera(View view) {
    Log.i(TAG, "starting Camera action");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    mImageCaptureUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    Log.d(TAG, "created media file uri is " + mImageCaptureUri);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);

}
```

In the onActivityResult the callback will be handled like this

```
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == ActionActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "received ok from camera intent, working on picture now. Saved image path is :" + mImageCaptureUri);
                b = new Bundle();

                if (mImageCaptureUri != null){
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    b.putSerializable("picUri", mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    i.setClass(this, AttachCommentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "error while processing camera result, there is no picture uri, going back to previous view");
                    startActivity(new Intent().setClass(this, ActionActivity.class));
                }
            }
```

Maybe the first time it works but afterwards the variable mImageCaptureUri  is always null. I could see in the logfiles that the activty has been stopped during the camera app is on foreground, thats explains why mImageCaptureUri is null. But how can I prevent this? Is it supposed procedure that the activity which is starting the app will be stopped? On my test device i am using android 5.0

Here is the log output

```
  07-01 11:39:49.224    5614-5614/de.myapp I/AttachActivity﹕ starting Camera action
  07-01 11:39:49.234    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ created media file uri is file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/pdixattach/IMG_20150701_113949.jpg
  07-01 11:39:49.264    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ activity has been paused!
  07-01 11:39:52.144    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ activity has been stopped!
  07-01 11:40:03.514    5614-5614/de.myapp E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {de.myapp/de.myapp.activies.AttachActivity}
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {de.myapp/de.myapp.activies.AttachActivity}
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3816)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3904)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:177)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
  07-01 11:40:02.984    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ activity has been created!
  07-01 11:40:03.014    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ request code in onActivityResult is  100
  07-01 11:40:03.014    5614-5614/de.myapp D/AttachActivity﹕ received ok from camera intent, working on picture now. Saved image path is :null
  07-01 11:40:03.014    5614-5614/de.myapp E/AttachActivity﹕ error while processing camera result, there is no picture uri, going back to previous view
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30977539/4447803 try this link it will work in lollipop

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532914/android-intent-with-multiple-option-i-e-pick-image-from-gallary-and-capture-im/29560548#29560548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could see in the logfiles that the activty has been stopped during the camera app is on foreground, thats explains why mImageCaptureUri is null.

Your process is being terminated due to low memory conditions. This happens frequently when invoking a third-party camera app.

> But how can I prevent this?

You cannot prevent your process from being terminated. You can, however, put the `Uri` into the `Bundle` passed into `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore the `Uri` in `onRestoreInstanceState()`. You should be doing that anyway, to handle screen rotations or other configuration changes.