# Image taken from camera cannot display in image view android 5.0, but working in android 4.4

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my activity code, when click on capture picture button, it will load camera from your phone. after i take a picture with camera, the picture will show at the imageView. Then i will click upload image picture button to upload my picture to server. Here the problem i faced, the code works well on all `android version 4.4` and below, when i test this code with `android 5.0`, the picture taken from camera wasn't show on the imageView. I had tried many solution and yet keep fail. Can anyone help me with this? thank you.

**Activity code**

```
public class TestUpload extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello camera";

private Uri fileUri;

private ImageView imgPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture, btnUploadImage;
private EditText itemname;
private EditText description;
private EditText price;
private EditText contact;

private String randNum, uname;

Random random = new Random();
private static final String _CHAR = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
private static final int RANDOM_STR_LENGTH = 12;        

private Spinner spinCat, spinLoc;

private String [] Category = {"IT Gadgets","Men Fashion","Women Fashion","Beauty","Sports","Cars and Motors","Furnitures","Music Instrument","Books","Property","Photography","Games and Toys","kids and Baby","Others"};
private String [] Location = {"Kuala Lumpur","Melacca","Johor","Selangor","Kelantan","Kedah","Negeri Sembilan",
        "Pahang","Perak","Perlis","Penang","Sabah","Sarawak","Terengganu"}; 

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

JSONParser2 jsonParser2 = new JSONParser2();

private static String url_create_image = "http://gemini888.tk/GP_trade_api_v2/image_connect/create_product.php";

private SweetAlertDialog pDialog;

long totalSize = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_test);

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#96ead7")));
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    btnUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
    itemname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_upload_item_name);
    description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_item_desc);
    price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.upload_input_item_price);
    contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_contact);
    spinCat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_category);
    spinLoc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_location);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_Category = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Category);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_Location = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Location);

    adapter_Category.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter_Location.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinCat.setAdapter(adapter_Category);
    spinLoc.setAdapter(adapter_Location);

    spinCat.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinLoc.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user = db.getUserDetails();
    uname = user.get("uname");

    //timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    randNum = getRandomString();
    //capture image button click event
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //capture image
            captureImage(); 
        }
    });

    btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                //uploading the file to server
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        }   
    });
}
//capturing Camera image will lunch camera app request image capture
private void captureImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    //Start image capture intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

//Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    //if the result i capture image
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //success capture image, display it on imageview
            previewCapturedImage(); 
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            //user cancel image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            //failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

//Display image from a path to imageview
private void previewCapturedImage() {


        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //bitmap factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        //downsize image as it throws Outofmemory execption for larger images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

//store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera app
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation change
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

//restore the fileUri again
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //get the Urifile
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

//create file Uri to store image
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

//returning image
private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    //External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), UserFunctions.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    //create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Failed create" + UserFunctions.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + "directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Create a media file name
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + uname + randNum + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

//upload image to server
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(TestUpload.this, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Picture uploading, please wait..");
        //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {

        String iname = itemname.getText().toString();
        String des = description.getText().toString();
        String iprice = price.getText().toString();
        String icontact = contact.getText().toString();

        String cat = spinCat.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String loc = spinLoc.getSelectedItem().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", iname));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", des));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", iprice));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", cat));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", loc));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", randNum));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", icontact));



        JSONObject json = jsonParser2.makeHttpRequest(url_create_image,
                "POST", param);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Log.d("Create Response", "success");
            } else {
                // failed to create product
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return uploadFile();            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }   
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String uploadFile() {
    String responseString = null;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UserFunctions.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                new ProgressListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void transferred(long num) {
                        setProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                    }
                });

        File sourceFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());

        // Adding file data to http body
        entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

        // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
        entity.addPart("website",
                new StringBody("http://gemini888.tk"));
        entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("thegemini888@gmail.com"));

        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                    + statusCode;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
    }

    return responseString;

}

public String getRandomString() {

    StringBuffer randStr = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i =0; i<RANDOM_STR_LENGTH; i++) {
        int number = getRandomNumber();
        char ch = _CHAR.charAt(number);
        randStr.append(ch);
    }
    return randStr.toString();
}

private int getRandomNumber() {

    int randomInt = 0;
    randomInt = random.nextInt(_CHAR.length());
    if (randomInt - 1 == -1) {
        return randomInt;
    } else {
        return randomInt - 1;
    }
}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spinCat.setSelection(position);

    String CatList = (String) spinCat.getSelectedItem();

    CatList.toString();

}





@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you getting the image url in onActivity result ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532914/android-intent-with-multiple-option-i-e-pick-image-from-gallary-and-capture-im/29560548#29560548

Answer (score 0):

in captureImage() method try this.

```
private void captureImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        try {
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Start image capture intent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //first of all create a directory to store your captured Images        
   String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/PGallery");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }

    //Give name to your captured Image
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    String sDate = formatter.format(date);
    imageName = "PRAVA"+sDate+".jpg";

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        filePath = new File(myDir,imageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(filePath));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

On Actvity Result:

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            ImagePath = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath, bitmapOptions);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCamreaPic);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```